# Get an image's alt text in a shortcode using the image URL

Tags: images, shortcode

I am creating a shortcode which looks like this:

```
[hpLocationSquare locationimage="...wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Enfielddetails.jpg"  /]
```

The `locationimage` attribute is the URL to an image in the media library.

In my functions.php I have the following code:

```
function hplocationsfn($atts, $content = null){
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'locationimage'=>''
    ), $atts));                     
return '<div class="locationSquare">
<a href="'.esc_attr($locationlink).'">
<img src="'.esc_attr($locationimage).'" />
</a>
</div><!-- locationSquare -->';
}
```

It works fine.

What I really want though is to somehow pick up the alt text for the image from the library. I could just add another attribute, but that would seem silly if it's already there. Is there a way I can get the alt text for the image?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `locationimage` attribute, why not use the attachment ID?

This will allow you to dynamically grab the URL to the file and will make getting other meta data such as the alt text much easier. Below is a rewritten version of `hplocationsfn()`.

Usage example: `[hpLocationSquare id='2299' link='http://example.com']`

Note that the `link` attribute is optional.

```
function hplocationsfn( $atts ) {
    // Set up shortcode attributes.
    // User provided values are stored in $atts.
    // Default values are passed to shortcode_atts below.
    // Merged values are stored in the $a array.
    $a = shortcode_atts( [
                'id'   => false,
                'size' => 'thumbnail',
                'link' => false,
    ], $atts );

    // Bail if we don't have an image.
    if ( ! $a['id'] ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the image and the image's alt value.
    $image     = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $a['id'], $a['size'] );
    $image_alt = get_post_meta( $a['id'], '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );

    // Bail if our image is invalid.
    if ( ! $image || empty ( $image ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Generate the output.
    $output = '<div class="locationSquare">';
    if ( $a['link'] ) {
        $output .= '<a href="' . esc_attr( $a['link'] ) .'">';
    }

    $output .= '<img src="' . esc_attr( $image[0] ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $image_alt ) . '"/>';

    if ( $a['link'] ) {
        $output .= '</a>';
    }
    $output .= '</div><!-- locationSquare -->';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'hpLocationSquare', 'hplocationsfn' );
```

It can be a bit of a pain for users to find the attachment ID, so here is a function that will add the attachment ID to the media overlay screen:

```
/**
 * Add custom field to media
 */
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'wpse_attachment_fields_id', 10, 2 );
function wpse_attachment_fields_id( $fields, $post ) {

    $fields['attachment_id'] = [
            'label' =>  __( 'Attachment ID', 'text-domain' ),
            'input' => 'html',
            'value' => $post->ID,
            'html'  => "<input type='text' class='text attachment_idfield' readonly='readonly' name='attachments[{$post->ID}][attachment_id]' value='" . esc_attr( $post->ID ) . "' /><br />",
            'show_in_edit' => true,
    ];

    return $fields;         
}
```

### Edit: Getting the attachment ID from the image URL

Alternatively, we can get the attachment ID from the image's URL using  [`attachment_url_to_postid()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_url_to_postid/).

**Example usage:**

```
[hpLocationSquare2 locationimage='http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/my-image.jpg' link='http://example.com/2/']
```

```
function hplocationsfn2( $atts ) {
    // Set up shortcode attrubutes.
    // User provided values are stored in $atts.
    // Default valued are passed to shortcode_atts below.
    // Merged valued are stored in the $a array.
    $a = shortcode_atts( [
                'locationimage' => false,
                'link'          => false,
    ], $atts );

    // Bail if we don't have an image.
    if ( ! $a['locationimage'] ) {
        return;
    }

    $image_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $a['locationimage'] );
    if ( ! $image_id ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the image and the image's alt value.
    $image_alt = get_post_meta( $image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );

    // Generate the output.
    $output = '<div class="locationSquare">';
    if ( $a['link'] ) {
        $output .= '<a href="' . esc_attr( $a['link'] ) .'">';
    }

    $output .= '<img src="' . esc_attr( $a['locationimage'] ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $image_alt ) . '"/>';

    if ( $a['link'] ) {
        $output .= '</a>';
    }
    $output .= '</div><!-- locationSquare -->';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'hpLocationSquare2', 'hplocationsfn2' );
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Dave - that's an interesting approach that I wasn't aware of. Thing is we're half way into the build, and the client is happily adding content so this would a bit of a change in approach. Is there no way of getting the image id from the url?

Comment: Turns out there's an easy way to do just that! Although it's not quite as efficient, I understand your situation :-)

Comment: thanks again Dave - I am trying to use the second method with a line `$image_id = wpse_get_attachment_id_from_url( $locationimage);` and it keeps coming back with 'undefined function' - where / what is this function please?

Comment: Sure! Sorry about that; the function should be `attachment_url_to_postid()`. I've updated the answer. I was using a custom function to get the image id from the URL before I realized that WP had added a core function to handle that.

Comment: fantastic Dave - really helpful and all working. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: just to say I used the two functions you suggested from the $locationimage